# XmlSerializer with parameterless constructor with no public properties or fields... Is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Having the following class (.Net 3.5):

```
public class Something
{
    public string Text {get; private set;}

    private Something()
    {
        Text = string.Empty;
    }

    public Something(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

This serializes without error but the resulting XML does not include the Text property since it does not have a public setter.

Is there a way (the simpler, the better) to have the XmlSerializer include those properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` only cares about public read/write members. One option is to implement `IXmlSerializable`, but that is a **lot** of work. A more practical option (if available and suitable) may be to use `DataContractSerializer`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Something
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Text {get; private set;}

    private Something()
    {
        Text = string.Empty;
    }

    public Something(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

This works on both public and private members, but the xml produced is not quite the same, and you can't specify xml attributes.

Comment: Thanks Marc,

That could work, I didn't know about this attribute. The two drawbacks you mentioned are they the only ones or are there other gotchas as well?

Comment: In many ways, it is a /better/ serializer (you'd hope so since it is newer) - but it has different aims. It isn't as flexible if you need tight control of the xml. But if you just want you data to serialize, then it should work. Or try protobuf-net ;-p

Comment: Note you need to add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization (from .NET 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

No.  XML Serialization will only serialized public read/write fields and properties of objects.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try
```

[Serializable]
public class Something
{
...
}

Comment: XmlSerializer doesn't need [Serializable], and it doesn't do anything at all towards letting you serialize read-only members.

Comment: It needs [Serializable] sometimes.

Comment: @Henk: when does it need [Serializable]?

Comment: No, sorry, I thought this was about the SOAPFormatter.